# MergeSort recursion explained

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

I know this question has been asked a lot and there are many useful and good answers but I have a specific question about the recursion. When we call sort recursively many times, what exactly happens?
Example: `int[] intArr = {16, 12, 9, 3, 19};`
When we split that array into 2 parts or look at it with two indices, what does `merge()` do with that two unsorted parts?
I mean in the first iteration the first two halfs are unsorted, right?
And the method should reach `merge()` with this current order:
`merge({16, 12}, {9, 3, 19})`

```
public static int[] sort(int l, int r) { 
     
    if (l < r) { 
        int q = (l + r) / 2; 
         
        sort(l, q); 
        sort(q + 1, r); 
        merge(l, q, r); 
    } 
    return intArr; 
}
```

I don't know what the problem is but I don't get the recursion behind Merge Sort completely. There's a basic understanding but the merge()-method makes it difficult for me.

Comment: Your merge sort will not work as it is currently syntactically incorrect. `intArr` is not defined. You should pass an array to `sort()` and `merge()` so it works for any array. I am assuming you have this method in some class which has a static attribute `intArr` here (in that case it would work, but you really should be using local variables here.

Comment: The array is indeed static but that's just for testing.

Comment: What prevents you from running the code with small example sets to see what happens?

Comment: To simplify @Mushroomator's answer, recursive merge sort just pushes indexes onto the stack via recursive calls until an instance of two pairs of indexes where each pair of indexes that represent a single element occurs. Only then does merging take place, merging two single element runs to create a sorted run of two elements. Then the call chain is followed up and down the stack, to create sorted runs of size 2, 4, 8, 16, ... .

Comment: [Bottom up merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation), skips all the recursion and starts off treating an array of n elements as n runs of size 1, and then proceeds to merge even and odd runs, creating runs of size 2, 4, 8, 16, ... . Most library implementations are some hybrid of insertion sort and bottom up merge sort. Recursive merge sort is mostly used for academic purposes, not actual implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `sort(0, 4)` for `intArr = {16, 12, 9, 3, 19}` you will have another call to `sort(0, 2)`, then `sort(0, 1)` and finally `sort(0, 0)`. When you reach that `l < r` will no longer hold true and you will return the unchanged array as an array with one element `16` is already sorted. So we are back to the call to `sort(0,1)` so the next thing would be the call to `sort(1,1)` where `l < r` will no longer hold true and you will return the unchanged array as `12` is a single element and therefore already sorted.
Only then you will reach the first `merge(0, 1)` call which will take `{16, 12, 9, 3, 19}` and sort all values from 0 to 1 so the result will be (assuming ascending order) `{12, 16, 9, 3, 19}`. Notice, that we call `merge(0, 1)` with two sorted arrays left and right from `q`. Then we have finished the `sort(0, 1)` call and move back to the previous `sort(0, 2)` call and now have a call to `sort(2, 2)`. This will return the array unchanged as `l < r` is no longer true and we move on to `merge(0, 2)` with the array `{12, 16, 9, 3, 19}`. The result of that call will be `{9, 12, 16, 3, 19}` and we've finished `sort(0, 2)` and move to `sort(0, 4)` and so on.

I suggest you debug through your program (or print the indices for your `sort()` calls) and you will see that the first `merge()` call only happens after a few calls to `sort()` and it will only ever be called for already sorted arrays left and right from it.

Also might be worth doing it on some paper so you get the concept.

```
16 12 9 3 19    Sort(0, 4)
16 12 9 | 3 19  Sort(0, 2)
16 12 | 9 3 19  Sort(0, 1)
16 | 12 9 3 19  Sort(0, 0)
^sorted 
16 | 12 9 3 19  Sort(1, 1)
      ^sorted 
12 16 | 9 3 19  Merge(0, 1)
  ^sorted
12 16 | 9 3 19  Sort(2, 2)
        ^sorted
9 12 16 | 3 19  Merge(0, 2)
   ^sorted
9 12 16 | 3 19  Sort(3, 4)
9 12 16 3 | 19  Sort(3, 3)
        ^sorted
9 12 16 3 | 19  Sort(4, 4)
             ^sorted
9 12 16 | 3 19  Merge(3, 4)
           ^sorted
3 9 12 16 19    Merge(0, 4)
all sorted
```

Comment: I guess there couldn't be a better answer for my problem. This explained it very well. I guess I didn't understand the whole algorithm until now. There's clarity now and the upcoming exercises from my prof shouldn't be difficult now ^^

Answer (score 0):

Take for granted that when `sort(i, j)` returns, the array is sorted in `[i..j]`.

Now `sort(l, q)` returns with `array[l..q]` sorted and `sort(q+1, r)` returns with `array[q+1, r]` sorted. Then `merge(l, q, r)` interleaves the two sorted subarrays in a single one so that `array[l, r]` becomes sorted (merging two sorted arrays is an easy operation).

Hence, mergesort sorts bigger and bigger arrays.

Notice that when `l==r`, the function returns immediately, because an array of a single element is perforce sorted.

Comment: I get that, that the array is sorted then. But I don't get what's happening when the merge method is called with unsorted parts of the array.

Comment: @soulcraft123: if you read my answer, you will understand that `merge` is *never* called with unsorted arrays.

Comment: I think I get it now. Big thanks!
I must have been blind or something but it's actually not that difficult.